# Ошибка валидации даты

Tags: java, rest, testng

Есть такой сервис:

```
import ru.lanit.rest.dao.PersonDAO;
import ru.lanit.rest.dto.CarDTO;
import ru.lanit.rest.dto.PersonDTO;
import ru.lanit.rest.model.Car;
import ru.lanit.rest.model.Person;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


@RequestScoped
@Path("/")
public class PersonService {

    @Inject
    PersonDAO personDAO;

    @Path("personwithcars")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @GET
    public Response getPersonWithCars(@QueryParam("personid") String personId){

        if (!isPersonIdIsLong(personId))
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        Long id = Long.parseLong(personId);

        Person person = personDAO.getPerson(id);
        if(person==null)
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();

        PersonDTO personDTO = setPersonDTO(person);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(personDTO).build();
    }


    @Path("person")
    @POST
    @Transactional
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addPerson(Person person){
        if(!isDateValid(person.getBirthdate()) || !isPersonIdIsLong(person.getId().toString()))
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();

        personDAO.addPerson(person);

        if (personDAO.getPerson(person.getId())!=null)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        else{
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    }

    private PersonDTO setPersonDTO(Person person){
        Set<Car> carSet = person.getCars();
        Set<CarDTO> cars = setCarDTO(carSet);
        PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonDTO();

        personDTO.setBirthdate(person.getBirthdate());
        personDTO.setId(person.getId());
        personDTO.setName(person.getName());
        personDTO.setCars(cars);
        return personDTO;
    }

    private Set<CarDTO> setCarDTO(Set<Car> carSet){
        Set<CarDTO> cars = new HashSet<>();
        for(Car car : carSet){
            CarDTO carDTO = new CarDTO();
            carDTO.setId(car.getId());
            carDTO.setModel(car.getModel());
            carDTO.setHorsepower(car.getHorsepower());
            carDTO.setOwnerId(car.getOwnerId());
            cars.add(carDTO);
        }
        return cars;
    }

    private boolean isPersonIdIsLong(String personId){

        try{
            Long.parseLong(personId);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isDateValid(final String date) {
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        String formatString = "dd.MM.yyyy";
        boolean isInvalidFormat;
        Date dateObj;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance();
            sdf.applyPattern(formatString);
            sdf.setLenient(false);
            dateObj = sdf.parse(date);
            if (date.equals(sdf.format(dateObj)) && dateObj.compareTo(currentDate)>0) {
                isInvalidFormat = false;
            }
            else {
                isInvalidFormat = true;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            isInvalidFormat = true;
        }
        return isInvalidFormat;
    }
}
```

Его проверяет такой тест: (конкретно вопрос про 29-30 строчки, где указана дата `"1995.18.03"`)

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import ru.lanit.RESTfulTest.parts.CarPost;
import ru.lanit.RESTfulTest.parts.PersonPost;
import ru.lanit.RESTfulTest.parts.PersonWithCarsGet;
import ru.lanit.RESTfulTest.tools.CarCreator;
import ru.lanit.RESTfulTest.tools.PersonCreator;
import ru.lanit.RESTfulTest.tools.Settings;

public class InvalidTest {

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {
        Settings.setup();
    }

    @Test
    public void beginTest(){

        //404 - request for /personwithcars

        PersonWithCarsGet.getPersonWithCarsTest("2", 404, "");

        //400 - requests

        JSONObject person1 = PersonCreator.createPerson("asd","InvalidPerson","1995.18.03");
        PersonPost.postPersonTest(person1, 400,null);

//        JSONObject car = createInvalidCar("15","BMW-X4");
//        CarPost = new CarPost(car,400,"");
//        CarPost.postCarTest();

        PersonWithCarsGet.getPersonWithCarsTest("asd", 400, null);

        person1 = PersonCreator.createPerson("1","Moja", "1995.18.03");
        PersonPost.postPersonTest(person1, 400,null);

        JSONObject car = CarCreator.createCar(15L,"To-yota-X56",200,1L);
        CarPost.postCarTest(car, 400,null);
    }
}
```

Класс, отвечающий за создание JSONObject person:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class PersonCreator {

    public static JSONObject createPerson(String id, String name, String birthdate){
        JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
        requestBody.put("id", id);
        requestBody.put("name", name);
        requestBody.put("birthdate", birthdate);

        return requestBody;
    }

    public static JSONObject createPerson(Long id, String name, Date birthdate){
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
        requestBody.put("id", id);
        requestBody.put("name", name);
        requestBody.put("birthdate", sdf.format(birthdate));

        return requestBody;
    }

    public static JSONObject createPerson(Long id, String name, String birthdate){
        JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
        requestBody.put("id", id);
        requestBody.put("name", name);
        requestBody.put("birthdate", birthdate);

        return requestBody;
    }
}
```

Вопрос: при отправки даты `"1995.18.03"` на проверку поступает дата `"16.11.0009"`. Не могу понять, почему?

Comment: Upd. в классе `Person` в методах `setBirthdate(String birthdate) ` и `getBirthdate()` используется `SimpleDateFormat.` Он и преобразует `1995.18.03` в `16.11.0009`. Как сделать иначе, я не знаю :/

Answer (score 0):

1. изменил сервис `PersonService`: убрал проверку валидности даты.
2. изменил сущность `Person`: добавил проверку валидности даты в метод `setBirthdate(String birthdate()`.

Изменённый класс PersonService:

```
import ru.lanit.rest.dao.PersonDAO;
import ru.lanit.rest.dto.CarDTO;
import ru.lanit.rest.dto.PersonDTO;
import ru.lanit.rest.model.Car;
import ru.lanit.rest.model.Person;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


@RequestScoped
@Path("/")
public class PersonService {

    @Inject
    PersonDAO personDAO;

    @Path("personwithcars")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @GET
    public Response getPersonWithCars(@QueryParam("personid") String personId){

        if (!isPersonIdIsLong(personId))
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        Long id = Long.parseLong(personId);

        Person person = personDAO.getPerson(id);
        if(person==null)
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();

        PersonDTO personDTO = setPersonDTO(person);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(personDTO).build();
    }


    @Path("person")
    @POST
    @Transactional
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addPerson(Person person){
//        !isDateValid(person.getBirthdate()) ||        add this to "if" if necessary
        if(!isPersonIdIsLong(person.getId().toString()))
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();

        personDAO.addPerson(person);

        if (personDAO.getPerson(person.getId())!=null)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        else{
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    }

    private PersonDTO setPersonDTO(Person person){
        Set<Car> carSet = person.getCars();
        Set<CarDTO> cars = setCarDTO(carSet);
        PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonDTO();

        personDTO.setBirthdate(person.getBirthdate());
        personDTO.setId(person.getId());
        personDTO.setName(person.getName());
        personDTO.setCars(cars);
        return personDTO;
    }

    private Set<CarDTO> setCarDTO(Set<Car> carSet){
        Set<CarDTO> cars = new HashSet<>();
        for(Car car : carSet){
            CarDTO carDTO = new CarDTO();
            carDTO.setId(car.getId());
            carDTO.setModel(car.getModel());
            carDTO.setHorsepower(car.getHorsepower());
            carDTO.setOwnerId(car.getOwnerId());
            cars.add(carDTO);
        }
        return cars;
    }

    private boolean isPersonIdIsLong(String personId){

        try{
            Long.parseLong(personId);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e){
            return false;
        }
    }

//    private boolean isDateValid(final String date) {
//        Date currentDate = new Date();
//        String formatString = "dd.MM.yyyy";
//        boolean isInvalidFormat;
//        Date dateObj;
//        try {
//            SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance();
//            sdf.applyPattern(formatString);
//            sdf.setLenient(false);
//            dateObj = sdf.parse(date);
//            if (date.equals(sdf.format(dateObj)) && dateObj.compareTo(currentDate)>0) {
//                isInvalidFormat = false;
//            }
//            else {
//                isInvalidFormat = true;
//            }
//        } catch (ParseException e) {
//            isInvalidFormat = true;
//        }
//        return isInvalidFormat;
//    }
}
```

Изменённый класс `Person`:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonBackReference;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name="birthdate")
    @NotNull
    private Date birthdate;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Car> cars;



    public Person(){}

    public Person(Long id, String name, String birthdate){
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
        try {
            setBirthdate(birthdate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Person(Long id){
        setId(id);
    }

    public void setCars(Set<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBirthdate() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

        return sdf.format(this.birthdate);
    }

    public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        if(isDateValid(birthdate))
        this.birthdate = sdf.parse(birthdate);
    }

    public Set<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }


    private boolean isDateValid(final String date) {
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        String formatString = "dd.MM.yyyy";
        boolean isFormatValid;
        Date dateObj;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance();
            sdf.applyPattern(formatString);
            sdf.setLenient(false);
            dateObj = sdf.parse(date);
            if (date.equals(sdf.format(dateObj)) && dateObj.compareTo(currentDate)<0) {
                isFormatValid = true;
            }
            else {
                isFormatValid = false;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            isFormatValid = false;
        }
        return isFormatValid;
    }
}
```